# jQuery AJAX loading with multiple a href links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm trying to get the following to work...

- demo_test.txt to load into the "div1" container
- only have a href id "test" to trigger it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("test").click(function() {
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
  </div>

  <a id="test" href="#">Get External Content</a>

  <br>

  <a id="google" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Currently it doesn't run, but if I remove the Google line, it works. Is there something else I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: There's no way that removing the google line could make it run. The problem is clearly due to the missing `#` in the `$("test")` selector.

Comment: Also, it looks like this is one of your first questions on StackOverflow- so welcome! Unlike on a forum, it's a good idea in the future to stick around on the site for an hour or so after you ask a question - that's when your question will get the most feedback and allow you to further explain your question if it isn't totally clear (in this case you're fine :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your jQuery click handler to this:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
```

I've added a `#` in front of `test` to properly select your anchor tag.